# How to make Selenium automation simple?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

Sorry for this weird question.

Actually we go for selenium-webdriver to make manual test simpler,but what I felt is, for finding each and every webelement itself a hectic job. I actually do 'n' number of test to test my selenium code. 
So, how can I make it simpler.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html please go through these..  There are lots of example with how to automate on selenium

Comment: You should focus on making the suite robust instead as most of the identification stuff is one time only

Comment: You could record your test in Selenium IDE and then convert it to Java. It would give you the basis for most elements, instead of searching them manually. Also creating reusable functions would help too.

Comment: 1. Get your developers to add IDs for the elements you are using. 2. Use Chrome Inspector's Ctrl-F search to test out XPaths and CSS Selectors (and even create them). 3. Get better at XPath and CSS selectors :)

Answer (score 0):

With my current experience with Selenium testing:

- write your own methods

If you have repetitive sequences of actions to check something - pack it in your own methods like: find, click or find, get text attribute, assert if true etc.

- make use of loops

Need to assert if text attribute is correct for N elements? Count number of elements, put your "testing" method inside loop for N repeats, compare against control-data stored in list/array etc.

- use all what testing-framework can provide

In my case I test with the help of NUnit. If I have set of similar or even identical tests, why not to use [[TestCase]](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5) instead of [Test]?

- refactor / simplify

If you realize during or after test development that some parts of code are redundant - just replace them with corresponding methods you created instead. Code will get much shorter quickly and will be much easier to update if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool fire-ie browser, this will help recognising elements without navigating to inspection page.

From below link, tool can be downloaded

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/fire-ie-selenium-tool-ie-browser/

Another option is use Selenium IDE to identify the element. This is suggested option only for the non-technical users.  Now Selenium IDE is available even on Chrome.

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way to find an element is by using css selectors. It is more natural and you can easily test your css selectors on chrome devtool by using the following construct like jquery, $('.classname').

BTW, I just created a small project to bootstrap a selenium project. You might want to check it out as it used shortcuts for selectors and I feel that it is more natural to have it that way, e.g. selector starts with '#' then us By.id, starts with '=', then use By.name.

Here's the project url: https://github.com/codezombies/easytest

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver is the most mainstream computerized test structure being utilized in programming improvement these days. Since it underpins all the principle programming dialects, for example, C#, Perl, Ruby, PHP, and JAVA, you have the opportunity to learn and make test code in any of these dialects. Selenium WebDriver+JAVA is the mix that is utilized the most. Obviously, information on HTML, javascript, and CSS is significant. Remember that an analyzer's employment is active. There will be numerous acceptable books on test mechanization. Nonetheless, the best preparation and range of abilities comes from dealing with genuine tasks.

Web advancement has expanded three-overlay contrasted and what it was years back. Various organizations are selecting to create sites to show their essence on the web. Also, testing is a significant piece of this web advancement measure. Concur? Obviously, it is. Most likely on that. In excess of a billion sites are live right now.

We see that various instruments are being delivered to assist with the turn of events and testing measures. On account of the web advancement specialists who are exploring and concocting good thoughts once in a while. You can discover various tooling alternatives on the lookout. Heaps of instruments are accessible to help you make your testing cycle simple and straightforward.

In a ton of testing instruments accessible out there, Selenium is perhaps the best device to date. The developing prominence of Selenium is a result of the wide scope of highlights that it offers. Selenium is open-source. You can download it liberated from cost. It is easy to comprehend and simple to utilize. With Selenium, you can play out your test on an assortment of programming dialects, for example, C#, Java, Python, etc, utilizing its Web Driver API. You can utilize it for mechanizing cell phones, including Android and iOS through Appium separated from for internet browsers.

Steps are as follows:

- Choosing a Framework for Testing
- How Do You Choose a Programming Language
- Choosing a Unit Test Framework
- Designing the Architecture of your Framework
- Choose a Mechanism for Reporting
- Building the “Selenium Test” Component